# How does Bokeh store datetime information

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, bokeh, epoch

I am using a Javascript callback to write the data stored in my bokeh `source` object to csv.

When I access the datetime column I get a strange format. 
The date representation for the entry `2017-03-16T00:00:00.000000000` becomes `938736000000` which does not seem to be in epoch milliseconds format.

How can I retrieve the readable datetime representation from the number representation?

Answer (score 0):

The value you get is probably the timestamp in microsecond format. It's harder to diagnose your problem without any source code, but you could try something like this:

```
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
```

and then use it for formatting:

```
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
    hours=["%d %B %Y"],
    days=["%d %B %Y"],
    months=["%d %B %Y"],
    years=["%d %B %Y"],
)
show(p)
```

Comment: It's not microseconds, it's *milliseconds* since epoch